# First and second derivatives of max function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, distribution-theory

I have two functions $f(x)=(x-K)_+$ and $g(x) = \max\{x,K\}, x \geq 0, K = const \geq 0$.

I was told that

$$f'(x) = \mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x)$$ and $$f''(x)=\delta_K(x),$$

because $(\mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x))'_x=\delta_K(x)$ and $f(x)=(x-K)_+ = (x-K)\mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x)$, where $\delta_K(x)$ is a delta-function.

Now I want to get derivatives of $g(x)$ and I was told that *they are the same*, but I can't understand why. My idea is that there should be something like ($x\geq 0$):

$$g(x) = \max\{x,K\} = x\mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x)+K\mathbb{I}_{[0,K)}(x) = x\mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x) + K(1 - \mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x)) $$

so the first derivative is

$$g'(x) = \mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x) + x\delta_K(x) - K\delta_K(x)$$

Here I'm unsure that I'm doing everything correct by representing indicator as $\mathbb{I}_{[0,K)}(x) = 1 - \mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x)$, but, anyway, I don't clearly understand how these derivatives were taken to obtain the similar result.

---

Edit: here is more information on what's going on: I'm studying the optimal stopping problem for the Black–Scholes model
$$dx(t) = x(t)(\mu dt + \sigma dW(t)), $$
cost function $$v(x) = sup_{\tau \geq 0} E[e^{-\beta \tau}g(x(\tau))],$$
$\tau$ is the stopping time we seek.

$f$ and $g$ from above are call  options. Here I need to study the expression (variational inequality)
$$\beta g -  \mathcal{L}g - \hat{f}$$ whether it is $\leq 0$ and not $\equiv 0$. Here $g$ is my option and the operator $\mathcal{L}$ is  $$\mathcal{L}\varphi(x)=\mu x\varphi'(x)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2\varphi''(x)$$
($\hat{f}$ is not the function above and is $0$ in his example).

In class we did the following for the option $f$ from above:

$$ \beta f - \mathcal{L}f  = \beta(x - K)_+ - \mu x  \mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x) - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2 \delta_K(x) \leq 0. $$

Comment: Note that $g(x) = f(x) + K$. Now all your generalised derivatives must be the same.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you! Now I'm starting to understand. But can you please explain me how the first derivative of $f$ was taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with you are speaking of distributions; that would be a good tag to add to your question.  In the calculus sense, $f(x)=(x-K)_+ = \max(x-K,0)$ is differentiable for $x\neq K$ and has no derivative at $x=K$, but with distributions one can give a meaning to the derivative of $f(x)$ as a distribution.  An example of a book that covers distributions is Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, chapter 6.

$f$ and $g$ are valid distributions because they are locally integrable, i.e., the integrals of $|f|$ and $|g|$ on compact sets are finite.

$g(x)=\max(x,K)=K+(x-K)_+=K+f(x)$ as noted in a comment while I was composing this answer.  You have now asked a new question, which is why $f'(x) = \mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x)$ in the distribution sense.  The short answer is that $f$ is almost everywhere differentiable and absolutely continuous, so its distribution derivative equals (the distribution corresponding to) its derivative as a function, with distributionhood allowing us to ignore the messy fact of having a point where $f$ is not differentiable.  Look at Rudin 6.14.  The derivative of $f$ as a function is $0$ for $x<K$, because it's uniformly zero there, and $1$ for $x>K$, because it's $x-K$ there.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check this book now! But I'm confused that it still seems that I can't use the product rule as I tried above and I won't know what to do if I meet a task with another function to differentiate.

Comment: The error in your reasoning seems to me simply writing $g(x) = x\mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x)+K\mathbb{I}_{[0,K)}(x)$.  The second term is not correct because it makes $g(x)=0$ for $x<0$, whereas $g(x)=\max(x,K)=K$ for $x<0$.

Comment: I have $x\geq$ 0 in my question, but it seems for me that I lack something very basic in understanding these derivatives. If $(\mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x))' = \delta_K(x)$, why not $f'(x) = (x-K)_+' = ((x-K)\mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x))' = (x\mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x) - K\mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x))' = \mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x) + x\delta_K(x) - K\delta_K(x)$

Comment: Or does that mean that I can just ignore all addends except $ \mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x)$, because I'm working with distributions and $x\delta_K(x) - K\delta_K(x)$ correspond to one point $x-K$ and mean actually nothing for distribution? But why we keep the second derivative of $f$ with delta function then, not just say that it is 0 in distribution?

Comment: In $g'(x) = \mathbb{I}_{[K,+\infty)}(x) + x\delta_K(x) - K\delta_K(x)$, $\delta_K(x)$ is concentrated at $K$, so $x\delta_K(x)-K\delta_K(x)=0$. Another way to see this is that for any test function $\phi$, we have $((x-K)\delta_K)\phi(x)=\delta_K\{(x-K)\phi(x)\}=(K-K)\phi(K)=0$.  See Rudin 6.15 (discussing the product of a function, in our case $x-K$, by a distribution, in our case $\delta_K$).  The second derivative of $f$ has a delta function because there's no such cancellation for that function.